# Why does the Visual Studio linker complain that CreateBkColor is not found

Tags: visual-studio-2019, arm64

I am trying to build a Windows DLL for ARM64.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 but the linker complains that it can't find the following Win32 API functions:

CreateSolidBrush
SetBkColor
DeleteObject

Why don't these functions exist for ARM64?

I am certain that I am linking with the Windows 10 SDK.

Comment: You have two problems.  Resolving the linker error is easy to do.  But surely won't solve the next big problem, finding a device that can actually execute your program.  Last time that was feasible was 11 years ago, back when WinCE was not yet fatally struck by an apple.  ARM64 is a target for mobile devices, the kind that are programmed with UWP and can't use the legacy GDI functions anymore.  Be sure to update the question with the project template you selected to get started as well as the make+model of the device you are programming for.

Comment: I am targeting the nascent crop of Windows on ARM64 laptops from Lenovo, and soon to be Microsoft itself (they are on the verge of announcing a Surface 2 in 1 with Qualcomm's SOC inside).  These devices use Qualcomm's new 8cx SOC.  The project template is windows console application but the application pops up a GUI built from Win32 GDI functions.  I thought that Microsoft is now supporting native Windows applications for ARM64.  This is not something they have done in the past but they support it now using VS2019 (but I could be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to explicitly add that you want to link against `gdi32.lib` (under Project, Properties, Linker, Input, Additional Dependencies). I guess it depends on the project template whether it is included by default. (It does seem to be added by default in the Windows Desktop Application template.)